# Concatenating a folder of quicktime files together

Tags: quicktime, cat, mov

I know on my linux box I can use:

```
cat file1.mov file2.mv file3.mov > combined.mov
```

But in OSX this doesn't seem to work. Only the file1.mov is combined.

Any work arounds for OSX?

Thanks

Comment: Definitely not programming related---voted to move to superuser.com. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FFMPEG FAQ](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC29), you have to convert your `.mov` files to MPEG format before you can concatenate them in that fashion.

Yes, you can use FFMPEG to do the conversion, both to and from MPEG. :-P